# How to combine different value return by Xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

```
<p class="pd-price">
    <img alt="€" src="http://www.redcoon.es/templates/tpl/img/pd/pd-price/euro_small.png">
    <img class="offsetStandard" alt="2" src="http://www.redcoon.es/templates/tpl/img/pd/pd-price/2.png">
    <img class="offsetStandard" alt="6" src="http://www.redcoon.es/templates/tpl/img/pd/pd-price/6.png">
    <img class="offsetStandard" alt="1" src="http://www.redcoon.es/templates/tpl/img/pd/pd-price/1.png">
    <img class="offsetStandard" alt="-" src="http://www.redcoon.es/templates/tpl/img/pd/pd-price/minus_point.png">
</p>
```

How to write an Xpath for this paragraph so that it will return "€261-". the Combine String of all the alt tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 string-join(p/img/@alt, "")
```

that will first select the text of all alt attributes and then combine it in a string

Comment: any other function instead of string-join. The Parser doesn't support this function. Can we Use concat any how ???

Comment: With concat you could do it like `concat(p/img[1]/@alt,p/img[2]/@alt,p/img[3]/@alt,p/img[4]/@alt,p/img[5]/@alt,p/img[6]/@alt,p/img[7]/@alt)`. (if there are more img in the concat call than in the html they are ignored). But it is better to switch to another parser that supports the most basic function.

Comment: If it supports xpath 2, you could also move the `p/` out to make it a little bit simpler `p/concat(img[1]/@alt,img[2]/@alt,img[3]/@alt,img[4]/@alt,img[5]/@alt,‌​img[6]/@alt,img[7]/@alt)`

Answer (score 0):

In Xpath 2, you have [string-join](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join)

```
string-join(p[@class='pd-price']/img/@alt, '')
```